# Create arrays from 1D array after every nth occurrence using Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, arrays

I have an array which looks like this

```
Array[20]
0 : "2"
1 : "3"
2 : "4"
3 : "5"
4 : "6"
5 : "7"
6 : "8"
7 : "9"
8 : "10"
9 : "11"
10: "12"
11: "13"
12: "14"
13: "15"
14: "16"
15: "17"
16: "18"
17: "19"
18: "20"
19: "12"
```

Now I want to create arrays after every 4th occurrence like this

**First Array**

```
0 : "2"
1 : "6"
2 : "10"
3 : "14"
4 : "18"
```

**Second Array**

```
0 : "3"
1 : "7"
2 : "11"
3 : "15"
4 : "19"
```

and so on...

Yet I have written this code

```
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.data.effort.length; i = i+ 4) {
    efforts.push( $scope.data.effort[i]);
 };
```

From above code I am getting only first array what should I need to do to get remaining arrays. Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is to run an extra loop outside that which handles your starting index. LIke this:

```
efforts = []
for (var j = 0; j < arr.length / 4; j++) {
  efforts[j] = []
  for (var i = j; i < arr.length; i = i + 4) {
    efforts[j].push(arr[i]);
  };
  console.log(efforts[j])
}
```

Here's working example: (simplified in JS, without `$scope` and all)

```js
var arr = [
  "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14",
  "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "12"
]
efforts = []
for (var j = 0; j < arr.length / 4; j++) {
  efforts[j] = []
  for (var i = j; i < arr.length; i = i + 4) {
    efforts[j].push(arr[i]);
  };
  console.log(efforts[j])
}
```

Or, interestingly, you can use the beast, I mean, [**`reduce`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to achieve the same. :)

```js
var arr = [
  "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14",
  "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "12"
]
efforts = arr.reduce(function(arr, cur, curIndex) {
  arr[curIndex % 4] = arr[curIndex % 4] || [];
  arr[curIndex % 4].push(cur);
  return arr
}, [])
console.log(efforts)
```

Comment: @Ramkishan glad I could help :)

Comment: Let me try this

Comment: Yes it is really interesting from the first one. once again thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Another simple way with array filter:

```
var originalArray =["2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20","21"];           
var firstArray = originalArray.filter((el, index) => (index%4 === 0));
var secondArray = originalArray.filter((el, index) => (index%4 === 1));
```

and so on